# Auxilio com PHP e HTML

Tags: php, html, tabela-html

Eu estou aprendendo php e html e gostaria de algum auxílio se possível, claro.
Eu tô criando uma tabela de acordo com umas variáveis passada como parâmetro e quando a mesma é criada !

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de retirar esses espaços a cada coluna que está sendo apresentado em branco. Alguém sabe como resolve. Obrigado desde já
Meu código tá bagunçado, confesso, pois tô aprendendo ainda, mas segue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

 <?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
 include_once("BDdados.php");
 $idSetorSelecionado = $_POST['setor'];
 $idCompentenciaSelecionado = $_POST['competencia'];
 $qtdeDeRegistro = $_POST['funcionarios'];

 echo "O setor selecionado no combobox foi " . $idSetorSelecionado . "<br>";
 echo "A competencia selecionado no combobox foi " . 
 $idCompentenciaSelecionado . "<br>";
 echo "O numero de funcionarios e " . $qtdeDeRegistro . "<br>";

 $strcon = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco);
 mysqli_set_charset($strcon, 'utf8'); // Configurar a conexão para usar 
 codificação UTF-8

 if (!$strcon) {
 die('Não foi possível conectar ao MySQL');
 }
 $sqlLookCompetencia = "SELECT nome, qtd_dias FROM competencia WHERE 
 id='$idCompentenciaSelecionado'";
 $resultadoLookCompetencia = mysqli_query($strcon,$sqlLookCompetencia) or 
 die(mysql_error()."<br>Erro ao executar a inserção dos dados");
 $elemento = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoLookCompetencia);
 $qtdeDeDias = $elemento['qtd_dias'];

$x = 1;
$y = 1; 
echo"<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo"<thead><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td colspan='2'>HORÁRIO</td><td colspan='2'>HORÁRIO INTRAJORNADA</td></tr></thead>";
echo"<tbody>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<th scope='col'>MATRÍCULA<th>";
echo"<th scope='col'>NOME COMPLETO<th>";
echo"<th scope='col'>NOME E Nº CONSELHO<th>";
echo"<th scope='col'>SETOR DE LOTAÇÃO<th>";
echo"<th scope='col'>ENTRADA<th>";
echo"<th scope='col'>SAÍDA<th>";
echo"<th scope='col'>ENTRADA<th>";
echo"<th scope='col'>SAÍDA<th>";
while($x <= $qtdeDeDias) {
    echo"<th scope='col'>".$x."<th>";
$x++;
} 
$x = 1;
echo "</tr>";

while($y <= $qtdeDeRegistro) {
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<th><th>";
    echo"<th><th>";
    echo"<th><th>";
    echo"<th><th>";
    echo"<th><th>";
    echo"<th><th>";
    echo"<th><th>";
    echo"<th><th>";
    while($x <= $qtdeDeDias) {
        echo"<th><th>";
        $x++;
    } 
    $y++;
    $x = 1;
} 
echo"</tr>";
echo"</tbody>";
echo"</table>";


?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, revise a tag `<th>`, pois você não está fechando-a, por exemplo, a linha:

```
echo "<th scope='col'>MATRÍCULA<th>
```

Repare que você não fechou a tag , basta fecha-lá:

```
echo "<th scope='col'>MATRÍCULA</th>
```

Revise as suas tags `<tr>` `<td>` e `<th>` e veja se ela está sendo fechada após a abertura das mesmas.